# Forecasting with Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to do some forecasting on some data I have. The tables below are just examples.

Basically I have an integer value x for today's date in a table.

```
todays_date, x
07/15/2018, 3
```

I have another query that has generated the monthly avg change of x for the past 3 years.

```
month, change
jan, 1
feb, 2
mar, 1
apr,-1
may, 1
jun, -2
jul, 2 ...
```

All I want to do now is create entries in a new table that would be the "forecast" for the next 6 months by adding the current months historical avg change to the current value of x and keep adding the change value for the next month to that number for the next 6 months. Putting a row in the table for each month.

```
todays_date, forecast_date, value
07/15/2018, 08/01/2018, 6
07/15/2018, 09/01/2018, 8
07/15/2018, 10/01/2018, 9
07/15/2018, 11/01/2018, 11
07/15/2018, 12/01/2018, 13
07/15/2018, 13/01/2018, 13
```

I could do this in Go but I would much rather do it in Postgres and possibly create a trigger to populate this forecast table.

Comment: Is the sample data you have shown the desired result or the input data? If it's the input data, then what exactly is the desired result? Please **[edit]** your question and add the new data you expect

Comment: I added some example data. Hope that helps.

Comment: If this is still relevant: Please provide a better example: In your result list you are starting with august (08) but your avg table ends in july. I think the avg table should be completed. Are the avg values the deltas between the value rows? What is 13/01/2018?